# DocuSign API: custom fields populating

Tags: docusignapi

I'm confused about the difference between "tabs" and "custom fields," perhaps --

When I send a json to DocuSign API's baseURL/envelopes, asking the API to send an envelope with a template, it works fine:

```
{ "accountId": "xxx",
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
   "emailBlurb": "Here's a document for you to sign",
   "templateId": "xxxx",
   "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "test@email.com",
            "name": "Test Person",
            "roleName": "parent_signer" }] }
```

When I try to add parameters for custom field filling, I get a 400 error:

```
{ "accountId": "xxx",
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
   "emailBlurb": "Here's a document for you to sign",
   "templateId": "xxxx",
   "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "test@email.com",
            "name": "Test Person",
            "tabs": [
               { "textTabs":
                  [
                     {"tabLabel": "Doc_Name",
                      "name": "Doc_Name",
                      "value": "Doc Name Data Would Go Here"}
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "roleName": "parent_signer" }] }
```

And the single document in my template in question has custom fields with those names. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF6F0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the document and page in which the tab needs to be displayed.
In JSON, it would look like below :

```
"textTabs": [
    {
        "tabLabel": "Doc_Name",
        "name": "Doc_Name",
        "value": "Doc Name Data Would Go Here",
        "DocumentId": "123",
        "PageNumber": "1"
    }
```

Comment: I added those parameters to the JSON, but still get the same result.

Comment: Did you replace it with the correct DocumentId ? What is the exact error message you get ?

Comment: The DocumentId is 1.   My code only gets the HTTP response code; is there a way to get something more specific?  `status = response.get('status');   if ((status not in ['200','201','204'])):    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); `

Comment: Yes, you should get an error code typically one of those listed by DocuSign [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/status_and_error_codes.html). Which language are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Python, and httplib2.request to make the calls.

Comment: For what it's worith, when I copy and paste the total JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ it validates.

Comment: Figured it out: too many square brackets.  It should be `"textTabs": { "tabLabel" not "textTabs": [ { "tabLabel"`  Creating a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will look at your newly created question

Answer (score 1):

"tabs" is not an array. There is a docusign exmaple here: 
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/templates

You're code should look like this:

```
    ...
    "templateRoles": [             // is an array
        {
            "email": "test@email.com",
            "name": "Test Person",
            "tabs": {              // is not an array (an object)
                "textTabs": [      // is an array (of objects)
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "Doc_Name", // should match Template "Data Label"
                        "name": "Doc_Name", // this field is unnecessary
                        "value": "Doc Name Data Would Go Here"
                    }
                ] // , other arrays of tabs like checkboxTabs may go here as well
            }
            "roleName": "parent_signer" }] }
```